# Convert Numbers into hh:mm time format

Tags: excel

I need to convert many values of this type:

```
855
1148
1030
1132
1136
1142
1217
1216
837
1044
```

into time values like this:

```
08:55
11:48
10:30
11:32
11:36
11:42
12:17
12:16
08:37
10:44
```

The end goal is to work out the average time from this list

Comment: So use the the time() function that takes hours minutes and seconds and pass it a copy of the left 1 plus length minus 3 characters for hours and the right two characters for minutes

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your values are in cells `A1:A10`, you could enter the formula:

```
=TIME(FLOOR(A1/100,1),MOD(A1,100),0)
```

into cell `B1` and copy down.

### Explanation:

The `TIME()` function takes three parameters - the number of hours, minutes and seconds.

By taking `FLOOR(A1/100,1)` we get the (rounded down) hundreds part of the value, which corresponds to the hours. By taking `MOD(A1,100)` we get the remainder upon dividing by 100, which gives us the minutes.

Once you have done this, you can simply use the `AVERAGE()` function to find the average.

Comment: Thanks. is there no way to convert, instead of copying into new cells? I have a whole spreadsheet of these...

Comment: @wazzahenry not that I can think of, no. It shouldn't be a particularly slow formula to calculate though?

Comment: If you encounter strange values like 7843, it will produce a valid time without issuing an error since: mod(7843,2400) = 643. You might want to check if the input value is less than 2400. Your example also doesn't seem to differentiate between AM and PM values.

Comment: @jobou it's calculating 78 hours and 43 minutes - which is the output I'd expect from an input like that. The only issue might come with formatting if the average is over 24 hours - which didn't seem to be the case from the provided inputs. The value will be correct regardless, it just might appear unusually.

Answer (score 1):

To do it without `TIME` (just for fun) also this is possible

```
=TRUNC(A1/100)/24+RIGHT(A1,2)/1440
```

or directly to get text:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&":"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```

or as a Sub (simply select the cells to convert an run it):

```
Sub test()
  Dim x
  For Each x In Selection.Cells
    x.Value = Int(x / 100) / 24 + (x Mod 100) / 1440
    x.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, Remember to format the column B as time,

```
=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"0\:00"))
```

[image]

You can apply average to this time in column B.

Comment: Thanks. My actual data covers an entire spreadsheet, is there a way to perform this formula over an entire spreadsheet?

Comment: @wazzahenry  just double click on the fill handle after pasting the formula in one cell. Doing so will autofill the formula to the entire range

Comment: if you want to replace all the values present in columns A to P, formulas is not the solution. You may have to go for vba