# Fomatting Via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(RowStart, TimeColNum), Cells(RowEnd, TimeColNum)).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
```

I want this code to convert a 3 digit or 4 digit number to hour and minutes ex.
330 -> 3:30
1520 -> 15:20
Currently the code converts any number with a value to 0:00.
I tried to find something online that might tell me why it is doing this but I've had no luck.

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145651/convert-numbers-into-hhmm-time-format)?

Comment: To clarify, why is it necessary that this be done in VBA vs using some of Excel's formulas?

Comment: To run all in one with another bit of code I'm making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, v
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each c In ws.Range(ws.Cells(rowStart, TimeColNum), ws.Cells(RowEnd, TimeColNum)).Cells
        v = c.Value
        If (Len(v) = 3 Or Len(v) = 4) And IsNumeric(v) Then
            c.NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
            c.Value = Left(v, Len(v) - 2) & ":" & Right(v, 2)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked very well Tim! Thank you so much!!